# Multiple Forms Email validation on a single page using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, validation, widget

I am developing a Wordpress Widget Plugin that inserts as many as you want email input forms in a widget.

I am using the following code to validate email fields

```
function validateForm(form) {
var x = document.forms["twb_form"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");

        if (x == null || x == "" || atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {

        document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email address';                   

        return false;                   
        }
}
```

The problem is that validation error always display along the very first form on page regardless of other forms...     This is because of the div #errorMSG

I know this can be solved using some kind of PHP tricks but I can't figure it out.

Every form on the page is being applied a separate ID ...   widget-id-1, widget-id-2  and so on...

How can I associate each validation message with a widget-id ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried below code?

```
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML ='';
    if (x == null || x == "" || atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {

    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email address';                   

    return false;                   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {  
    var elm = {};  
    var elms = document.getElementById(containerID).getElementsByTagName("*");  
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {  
        if (elms[i].id === childID) {  
            elm = elms[i];  
            break;  
        }
    }
    return elm;
}
```

and in your function

```
var elem= GetElementInsideContainer(widgetID, 'errorMSG');
elem.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email address';
```

found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171483/simple-way-to-get-element-by-id-within-a-div-tag)