# When using javascript, how do I set the <div> that will change images?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Basically, I have an html document that has some static images and images I would like to change on a timer. I've got that working, but the rotating images go to the first `<img>` in the html, which is supposed to be static. How do I designate where to put the changing images?

This is what I have, and it works - the images change, but not where I want them to.

```
<html>
<div id="staticImage">
    <img src="pic1">
</div>

<div id="changingImage">
    <img id="changePics">
</div>

</html>

//My javascript to rotate the images:

var imageArray = [];
var index = 0;`

function loadImages(){
    imageArray[0] = new Image();
    imageArray[0].src = "img/a.jpg";
    imageArray[1] = new Image();
    imageArray[1].src = "img/b.jpg";
    imageArray[2] = new Image();
    imageArray[2].src = "img/c.jpg";
    imageArray[3] = new Image();
    imageArray[3].src = "img/d.jpg";`

    document.images[0].src = imageArray[0].src;}

function rotateImage() {
    index ++
    if (index > 3) {
        index = 0}
    document.images[0].src = imageArray[index].src;}


//The javascript always lands in the "staticImage" `<div>`.
```

Comment: What will cause `rotateImage()` function to execute?

Comment: Well you're saying the first `<img>` element in the document by `document.images[0]`, so if you want the second one, use `document.images[1]`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `document.images[0].src` will always return the first image in the document. Looking at the HTML part, `staticImage` is coming ahead of `changingImage`so, `loadImages` and `rotateImage` will always change the first image in the DOM structure.

One way can be passing element IDs into the functions and the functions change images from the passed IDs.

Here is a hint, which would probably help you to solve the issue.
[Simple way to get element by id within a div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171483/simple-way-to-get-element-by-id-within-a-div-tag)

If you you can't figure it out, then come back again.

Comment: I just saw it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this with JavaScript has it will impact performance on browser and mobile depending who your audience is but you should prepare for both. The best way to do this is by using CSS and carousel through the images. Basically you create a `div` with `overflow-x:hidden` and cycle through the images moving from left to right every second or so. I provided a howto with a demo for you to try out.

[howto with demo](http://csswizardry.com/2011/10/fully-fluid-responsive-css-carousel/)