# Creating a callback function containing if else statement

Tags: javascript

the problem I have is that I would like to use an if else statement in a callback function like this:

```
alertNotify("alert","Do you want to delete this",function(delete) {
   if(delete) {
      //do code
   }else {
      //do nothing
   }
});
```

current function code:

```
    function alertNotify(text,type) {
    $("body").append("<div id = 'alert' class='common'>\
                        <div id ='content'class='common'>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>");
    var alert = $("<div id = 'ok' class='common'>\
                     Ok\
                  </div>\
                  <div id = 'cancle''class='common'>\
                    Cancle\
                  </div>");
    var rename = $("<div class='common rename_it'>\
                      Ok\
                    </div>");
    var type_file = $("<input type='text' id ='rename'><div id='hover'></div>");
    if(type == "alert") {
        $("#content").append(text);
        $("#content").append(alert);
    }
    if(type == "rename") {
        $("#content").append(rename);
        $("#content").append(type_file);
    }
    $("#ok").click(function() {
        $("div").remove("#alert");
    });
    $(".rename_it").click(function() {
        $("div").remove("#alert");
    });
    $("#cancle").click(function() {
        $("div").remove("#alert");
    });

}
```

I would like the if statement to differentiate between whether the #ok div was clicked or the #cancel div was clicked but I have no idea where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: What’s passed to the callback? i.e. what function are you actually using to prompt?

Comment: An alert does not have a yes,no.... So that is a bad design if you are overriding window.alert....

Comment: Where and how are you using this. Maybe you want consider to use the javascrpt confirm function and not the alert function. Can you post the relevant code so we don't hvr to guess please?

Comment: Why don't you just attach separate Events to each Element? By the way we don't see any `onclick` code here, or any Event for that matter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but i should be alertNotify() not alert(). This is a custom function I made up to overcome the UI limitaions of alert().

Comment: For the record, I can get it working by using jquery click events for the two divs outside the function body and make it do something but this is obviously not wanted,

Comment: So, how do you plan on catching the click event on your elements? Without an event listener I don't see how.

Comment: Maybe i could use the event listener in the function and use 'return  callback(true); / callback(false);

Comment: @TheDudeAlexNuzum passing the actual delete function as a callback to the "pretty" confirm box is a solid workaround

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry about that little bit of confusion. If I had of explained myself properly someone else might have answered but instead i got it. Add paremeter called callback and simply return callback(true); when the ok button is clicked and then my USB stopped working....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `confirm` instead:

```js
document.getElementById("prompt").onclick=function(){
  if(confirm("Do you want to delete item?")){
    // Delete
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "deleted";
  }else{
   // Don't delete
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "spared";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="prompt">delete item</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: `confirm == true` is redundant, as if statements already coerce to Boolean

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are trying to do something like this

```
if( confirm("Do you want to delete this")){
    //delete
}else{
   // do not delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In raw JavaScript your code might look something like:

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // if previous onload run here using this type of Event handler

var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var ok = E('ok');
ok.onclick = function(){
  console.log('ok was clicked');
}
// another way to use E
E('cancel').onclick = function(){
  console.log('cancel was clicked');
}

}
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need event listeners on each element. So you can use something like

```
var element0 = document.getElementById(divID);
element0.addEventListener('click', funcDivClicked(element0));
```

To put a click event listener on all of them with a loop, see here:
[Simple way to get element by id within a div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171483/simple-way-to-get-element-by-id-within-a-div-tag)

I suggest using window.confirm instead of alert:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

```
function funcDivClicked(el){
    var cBox = confirm("Delete "+el.getAttribute("id")+"?");
    var strAction;
    if (cBox == true) {
        strAction = "You pressed OK";
        //deletes the element
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    } else {
        strAction = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    console.log(strAction);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check the `target` within the event handler:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){
       if(e.target.id === 'ok'){
         alert('ok');
       } else if(e.target.id === 'cancel'){
         alert('cancel');
       }
    });
```

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){
       if(e.target.id === 'ok'){
         alert('ok');
       } else if(e.target.id === 'cancel'){
         alert('cancel');
       }
    });
```

```css
div {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  }

div#ok {
  background: green;
  }

div#cancel {
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="ok">Ok!</div>
<div id="cancel">Cancel!</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div').addEventListener` isn’t a thing.